# How can I register a Prestashop components JavaScript file?

Tags: php, symfony, prestashop, hook

I am looking to register a Javascript file in prestashop 1.7.

I want to use `registerJavascript()` for this.

The file is in "themes/new-theme/js/components/choice-table.js".

But my code doesn't work :

```
  public function hookHeader($params)
    {
        $this->context->controller->registerJavascript(
            'choice-table',
            'themes/new-theme/js/components/choice-table.js',
            [
                'priority' => 150,
                'position' => 'bottom',
                'attribute' => 'defer'
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I had finally to bundle the file 'choice-table.js' with webpack.